# How to create round line caps in circular progress bar

Tags: wpf, styles

So i have this `Circular Progress-Bar`:

[image]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Border>
                <Path x:Name="pathRoot" 
                  Stroke="{Binding SegmentColor, ElementName=userControl}"
                  StrokeThickness="{Binding StrokeThickness, ElementName=userControl}" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Height="100"
                  Width="100">
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                            <PathFigureCollection>
                                <PathFigure x:Name="pathFigure">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <PathSegmentCollection>
                                            <ArcSegment x:Name="arcSegment" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                                        </PathSegmentCollection>
                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathFigureCollection>
                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

And i want my `Circle` border will be rounded, for example:

[image]

Any idea how to do that ?

I try to put my main `Grid` inside `border` with some corner value but this did not wirk..

Comment: Did you try [StrokeStartLineCap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.strokestartlinecap(v=vs.110).aspx) and `StrokeEndLineCap` on the `Path`? I.e. set it to `Round`.

Comment: OK thats works fine, can i change this round value ?